# Run a GET Webhook During a Call for the Transcribed Message in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible to do a GET call for the transcription of an incoming call while it is in progress with Twilio?

I have been able to get it to run the call, but the transcription text initially shows up as Null. When I end the call, I can get the transcription. Does more time need to pass in order to be able to pull the text? Or does the call need to end first?

I am trying to build a portion of an IVR tree that will check the transcription time, and see if it contains certain text before moving to the next task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I did some more testing and set the message after the record widget to continuously repeat for about 30 seconds and I ran continuous commands to the transcriptions page for the call. After about 10 seconds, the transcription populated.